# Gradle maven-publish plugin fails on sub-projects

Tags: github, build.gradle, maven-publish

Following this guide:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-package-registry

But when I apply the gradle's maven-publish to the submodules, I get the following error:

> Could not find method publications() for arguments [build_81s2rz8tveop6ddsgghnyy4gk$_run_closure1$_closure4@395cd54] on project ':cms-data-contract' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

and the task fails

I tried to apply the maven-publish plugin explicitly in that subproject but it did not work. The plugin is applied as can be seen in this log statements:

:25:11.198 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.api.publish.plugins.PublishingPlugin to project ':cms-data-contract'' started
14:25:11.198 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.api.publish.plugins.PublishingPlugin to project ':cms-data-contract''
14:25:11.198 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.api.publish.plugins.PublishingPlugin to project ':cms-data-contract'' completed

and

14:22:51.786 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :cms-data-contract:publishAllPublicationsToGitHubPackagesRepository' started
14:22:51.787 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :cms-data-contract:publishAllPublicationsToGitHubPackagesRepository'
14:22:51.787 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :cms-data-contract:publishAllPublicationsToGitHubPackagesRepository' completed

I am using the following:

```
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: "maven-publish"
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "GitHubPackages"
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY")
                credentials {
                    username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("GPR_USER"))
                    password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") ?: System.getenv("GPR_API_KEY"))
                }
            }
        }
        publications {
            gpr(MavenPublication) {
                from(components.java)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The guide is suggesting to use:

```
plugins {
    id("maven-publish") apply false
}
```

but that fails with an exception

I should be able to publish the artefact to the github registry

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need complete those properties  correctly

1. `OWNER`
2. `REPOSITORY`
3. `GPR_USER`
4. `GPR_API_KEY`

see @link https://github.com/youngerier/packagesdemo